# How to implement select2 in laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, laravel-5, jquery-select2

I have simple input I would like to user select js [select2js](https://select2.org/)

Here is my input

```
<div class="form-group">

    <select class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        ...
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>

    <!-- Button trigger modal -->

</div>
```

in my `app.blade.php (master)` I have this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2()
});
```

Now when I run my app I get this error

```
caught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (create:420)
at j (jquery.min.js:1197)
at k (jquery.min.js:1203)
```

> In console network both js and CSS for select2 are loaded

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be due to one of the following reason:

- Your select2 JS is not added in right place, like you need to add it after jQuery
- Other JS scripts might have throwing an error which causing all other JS scripts to breaks
- Your jQuery version is not compatible with the select2 jQuery plugin
- You may have multiple jQuery added for different jQuery plugin